# How to get profile pictures of all Azure AD b2c users using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

**I want** to get profile picture of all b2c users.

**I have tried** to get profile picture of logged in user and its working, but I didn't found way to get profile picture of  other b2c users.

```
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<token>");
                    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
```

**I have tried** to get all b2c user profiles by using following code, and able to get all user profiles data but photos are not available in that.

```
       var result = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        List<Microsoft.Graph.User> users = (List<Microsoft.Graph.User>)result.CurrentPage;
```

Please help me for this !!!

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What is the user attribute? Is it a local user or a social user?

Comment: Why do you think a B2C user has a photo on the user object in AAD B2C. Did you set one? By default there won’t be any photo.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the profile data of all the users, just iterate over them and use the id of each user:

```cs
var photoStream = await graphClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

For testing you can use Postman, where the call would be like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/photo/$value
```

Check out [the link to the microsoft postman collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman)

Comment: Not working...
as already i have described in question,
Photo not available in profile data.[Photo = null]

Comment: in your question you didn't show, what you already tried. above call works in my example application and also in postman - so perhaps try your call in postman first, there you get a more detailed answer instead of only Photo = null;

Comment: @Umang What the answer here was saying is that you have to loop through your profile list of data and take the id of the user and put it into the URL above to get a single users photo. The loop is so that you call that for each user you have in your list. Unfortunately, it is a one by one call. I wish there was another way to reduce the number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for Azure b2c users, it is currently not possible to call the Graph API, so you cannot get the profile pictures of all Azure AD b2c users by calling the Graph API:   https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/526

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Graph, the photo is handled by the Exchange service, except there are certain cases where this won't work.  B2C appears to be one of those cases because B2C tenants don't get licensed for Exchange.  The alternative, for now, is to use the Microsoft Graph /beta endpoint.  That should work, as it falls back to AAD to get/set photos.